# spellcheck collate - How to return suggestion which is more frequent in the index

Tags: solr

I am using this option to see the frequency of the spell check suggestions.
spellcheck.extendedResults=true.
If I use spellcheck.collate=true, and collate seems to pick up the best suggestion but not the most frequent term.
Is there a way to configure it to return most frequent term in the index?
I saw the thresholdTokenFrequency which I am yet to try. But as it says in the documentation,   prevents low-instance terms from being offered as spelling suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=true`. This should return hits by their frequency ("popularity") in the index. I don't have an applicable core to test that this also changes the result from `collate`, but I'd think so.

> if this parameter is set to true then the suggestions will be sorted
>   by weight ("popularity") - the count parameter will effectively limit
>   this to a top-N list of best suggestions. If this is set to false then
>   suggestions are sorted alphabetically.